# WPF - Problem with displaying an Image with BitmapImage as a source

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap

I have always been using MVVM model when creating applications with WPF and everything connected with displaying/modifying Bitmaps worked well, however this time I have decide to choose other way as I want to adjust Bitmap width and height to the control that should contain it, but something doesn't work here.

I use an event  that is executed on Load as I want to get the actual height and width as said before.

Part of my code:

```
    private BitmapImage scene;
    public BitmapImage Scene
    {
        get { return scene; }
        set { if (scene != value) { scene = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Scene"); } }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;

        LoadSceneCommand = new RelayCommand(LoadScene);
        GenerateTexturedCylinderCommand = new RelayCommand(GenerateTexturedCylinder);
        GenerateTexturedSphereCommand = new RelayCommand(GenerateTexturedSphere);
        GenerateCylinderShadingCommand = new RelayCommand(GenerateCylinderShading);
        GenerateSphereShadingCommand = new RelayCommand(GenerateSphereShading);
    }

    private void GetSceneSize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object wantedNode = (Grid)this.FindName("SceneGrid");
        if (wantedNode is Grid)
        {
            Grid imageControl = wantedNode as Grid;

            sceneWidth = (int)imageControl.ActualWidth;
            sceneHeight = (int)imageControl.ActualHeight;

            try
            {
                PrepareScene();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void PrepareScene()
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(sceneWidth, sceneHeight);

        for (int x = 0; x < sceneWidth; ++x)
            for (int y = 0; y < sceneHeight; ++y)
                bitmap.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);

        Scene = ImageConverters.Bitmap2BitmapImage(bitmap);
    }
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="_3DRendering.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="GetSceneSize"
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">

<Window.Resources>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SceneGrid">
        <Image Source="{Binding Scene}" x:Name="ImageControl"/>
    </Grid>

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel>
            <StackPanel.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0 10 0 0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5 5 5 5"/>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Resources>

            <Button Content="Textured cylinder" Command="{Binding GenerateTexturedCylinderCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Textured sphere" Command="{Binding GenerateTexturedSphereCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Cylinder shading" Command="{Binding GenerateCylinderShadingCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Sphere shading" Command="{Binding GenerateSphereShadingCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Load Scene" Command="{Binding LoadSceneCommand}"/>
            <Button Content="Save Scene" Command="{Binding }"/>

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

As you can see I try to make the whole Bitmap black. Unfortunately the result that I get is that nothing is displayed. It is just a blank white space in the place where my Bitmap should be shown.

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to use the WinForms Bitmap class. You can use WriteableBitmap when you need to have access to the raw pixel buffer. Or you create a BitmapImage with setting its DecodePixelWidth or DecodePixelHeight properties.

Comment: If you would tell us what you are actually trying to achieve, we might perhaps offer a more suitable approach.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it, however I guess it won't solve the problem, right?

Comment: Not sure what the actual problem is. Maybe your ImageConverters class? Besides that, using SetPixel to initialize each single pixel is extremely inefficient.

Comment: @Clemens Well, the final goal is complex, however to get started I just want to make my Image to be displayed and as I wrote it doesn't go well. After assigning black color to each pixel still nothing changes and I am left with an empty Image that is contained in my .xaml

Comment: @Clemens Yeah, I know about the SetPixel inefficiency, I will change it in the later phase. For now I just use the things that are easy to code to check if finally the Image will be shown. About the ImageConverters I have used them for a while as a template and they have been always working correctly so that can't be a problem.

Comment: Many things may have gone wrong. Did you debug your code to make sure that sceneWidth and sceneHeight aren't zero?

Comment: `(Grid)this.FindName("SceneGrid");` also looks totally odd. If there is a Grid with `x:Name="SceneGrid"` you will get a generated field that you could use directly, i.e. `Grid imageControl = SceneGrid;`. Besides that using `as Grid` after `(Grid)FindName` is totally redundant.

Comment: @Clemens Yeah, they are set correctly. Nothing close to zero. I have even tried using constant values as 300, ..., but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Seriously, consider `Scene = new WriteableBitmap(sceneWidth, sceneHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);`

Comment: @Clemens Won't using typical Bitmap with Lockbits give the same result? At least in the terms of efficiency? I am more experienced with them.

Comment: You would always have to convert it to a BitmapSource. Not very efficient.